# install redmine on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache, redmine

I am trying to get redmine running on an Ubuntu 18.04 with apache.
I followed these instructions: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-configure-redmine-on-ubuntu-1804/
without any problems.

Apache is running and I can access the default apache page "it works" at: http://192.168.178.100/.
But if I try to open the redmine at: http://192.168.178.100/redmine_test I just see the content of the folder (public folder and Gemfile.lock). No website at all.

my **redmine_test.conf** looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin example@example.de
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine_test
 ServerName 192.168.178.100/redmine_test
 ServerAlias www.192.168.178.100/redmine_test

 <Directory /var/www/html/redmine_test>
     RailsBaseURI /redmine_test
     PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**sudo systemctl status apache2:**

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-03-02 11:15:13 CET; 18s ago
  Process: 12954 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7476 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12964 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 37 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─13028 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13029 vlogger (access log)
           ├─13032 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13033 Passenger watchdog
           ├─13037 Passenger core
           ├─13042 Passenger ust-router
           ├─13069 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13070 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13071 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13072 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13073 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13074 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─13075 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─13076 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Mar 02 11:15:13 server1 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 02 11:15:13 server1 apachectl[12964]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release
Mar 02 11:15:13 server1 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**Edit:**
If I test the installation by running WEBrick web server

```
bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
```

Everything works as aspected on: http://192.168.178.100:3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved: The DocumentRoot need to point to public:

```
/var/www/html/redmine_test/public
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing Passenger part of that tutorial.

Redmine is Ruby on Rails based application, and in order to make it run under Apache, you need at least one of following models to deploy RoR application:

1. Running via app server like puma, webrick, thin... and served through apache as reverse proxy
2. Running via passenger as a module
3. Running as a CGI

In the tutorial that you have seen, it's no=2, but in the Apache config that you submitted there seems to be passenger missing.

Try enabling passenger with following command:

```
sudo a2enmod passenger
```

Comment: When I run "sudo a2enmod passenger" i get "Module passenger already enabled". My passenger.conf looks exactly like shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Apache `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives should contain symbolic (non-IP) values. So if you have registered some domain name you should use it.

If you haven't one, you can use any domain name you want (for *development/testing purposes* of course). Assume you choose `redmine.dev`, then

1. Edit `redmine_test.conf`

```
ServerName redmine.dev
ServerAlias www.redmine.dev
```

2. Add to `/etc/hosts` **on the box where you open the browser and point it to `redmine.dev`**

```
192.168.178.100 redmine.dev www.redmine.dev
```

3. Point the browser to `redmine.dev` or `www.redmine.dev` and you'll see Redmine interface.